# How to find a visible anchor element and click it in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find a anchor which is displayed to click. Calculating all the elements and using isDisplayed() is not optimal . Is there a faster , more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your anchor element is :

```
List<WebElement> elem =driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath\to\anchor"));

if(elem.size() >0)
{

System.out.println("Element is present" + elem.get(1).getText();
 }
```

or, to verify whether this element is displayed or not you can use a custom method as:

```
public boolean isPresent(WebElement element){

 try{
      elem ;

      return true;
    }
catch(Exception e){

      return false;

    }
}
```